# using a variable in <a> tag(html)

Tags: javascript, html, variables, aem

I have a variable image in which I have got the value from a string array, e.g.:

```
string image=navdata[1].
```

Now I have to include this image variable in an anchor tag (HTML).

Can anyone help regarding this?

I'm using javascript and I'm working in day CQ5.

Comment: What server-side language are you using? (for example, PHP)

Comment: Is this JavaScript code? C#? Java? PHP? Sancrist maybe?

Comment: i m using javascript. and i m working in day CQ5.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others here I am not sure what you want exactly, but it seems as if you want to display a image from an array using Javascript. To do this you can use `document.write()` and combine the HTML content you need with the Javascript variables.

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var ImageArray = ['Image01.png','Image02.png','Image03.png'];
    document.write('<img src="' + ImageArray[0] + '" alt="" />');

</script>
```

Comment: no this is not what i need. my question is:

String[] navData=(properties.containsKey("list"))? properties.get("list",String[].class):null;
 String image="";
if(null!=navData)
{  

for(int i=0;i<navData.length;i++){
String[] navItem=navData[i].split("\\|");


                    

                    String title=   navItem[0];  
                      out.println(title);
                    image =  navItem[1];
                    
                    
                    
                              
                   
      
}
}
%>

Comment: Now what i want is to include a <div> in which i can use the <a> tag to display the image retrieved in variable 'image'.

Comment: @ht_ct - If you need this code to explain your question, you should edit your question and put this code in.